# ArgumentNullException with StaticExtension

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

### Problem

This works:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Style.BasedOn>
          <x:StaticExtension Member="l:SharedResources.ButtonStyle" />
     </Style.BasedOn>
</Style>
```

But with this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       BasedOn="{x:Static l:SharedResources.ButtonStyle}" />
```

I get an `ArgumentNullException` at `StaticExtension.MemberType.set(System.Type value)` with the message:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: value

Why?

---

#### Possibly useful background information

- `l:SharedResources` is a static class with multiple static `Style` properties

  ```
  public class SharedResources : ResourceDictionary
  {
      // other stuff
      public static Style ToolBarButtonStyle { get { /* stuff */ } }
      // other styles
  }
  ```

  and using the styles in xaml has worked without a hitch except in the case above.
- A breakpoint at the property getter is never hit before the exception, but in the working case, it does get hit.